# Multer Unexpected field

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm trying to upload a file into my project using multer, but I have no idea how to do it.

here's some of the code I wrote thinking it could work

// here's my ejs view

```
<form action="/wistia" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

// here's my route file

```
const multer = require("multer");
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

let location = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');
let upload = multer({ dest: location });

router.get("/wistia",function(req, res){
    res.render("wistia");
});
router.post("/wistia", upload.single("archivo") , function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

thanks.

Comment: So, Was it successful? (or) Do you receive any errors?

Comment: Im getting an error

`Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (C:\Users\JustBrian\Desktop\zen\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\JustBrian\Desktop\zen\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JustBrian\Desktop\zen\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at emitMany (events.js:127:13)`

Comment: Can you try replacing your `let location = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');` as `let location = multer({ dest: 'uploads/'});` ?

Comment: done yet the same error https://imgur.com/a/FbSfl , here's also a picture of the error http://i.imgur.com/45HJX4Z.png

Answer (score 0):

Try making this change

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null,location);
    }
  })
});
```